# Issue with Nested State in Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create 2 separate URL states within the same config file.

I was following this template below.

```js
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
      data:{
         customData1:  "Hello",
         customData2:  "World!"
      }
   })
   .state('parent.child', {
      data:{
         // customData1 inherited from 'parent'
         // but we'll overwrite customData2
         customData2:  "UI-Router!"
      }
   });
```

My code is below. The /reports/moveFrom works fine; however, the /drillDown route is not even registering. Hitting that url sends me back to my apps homepage.

I'm wondering if the parent.child notation is getting messed up by the app.report_moveFrom.drillDown as it has 2x (.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.report_moveFrom', {
      url: '/reports/moveFrom',
      views:{
        'main': {
          template: require('./moveFrom.html'),
          controller: 'moveFromController as $ctrl'
        }
      },
      title: 'moveFrom'
    })
    .state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
      url: '/drillDown',
      views:{
        'main': {
          template: require('./drillDown.html'),
          controller: 'moveFromController as $ctrl'
        }
      },
      title: 'drillDown'
    })
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ui-router` doesn't support more than one `.` when defining routes.

Comment: That was my thinking. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the code that you using to make a call.
You should be calling something like this:

```
/reports/moveFrom/drillDown
```

If you are not doing this, kindly change it once and check

This is the piece from the lib:

$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/contacts',

```
    // Note: abstract still needs a ui-view for its children to populate.
    // You can simply add it inline here.
    template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('contacts.list', {
    // url will become '/contacts/list'
    url: '/list'
    //...more
})
.state('contacts.detail', {
    // url will become '/contacts/detail'
    url: '/detail',
    //...more
})
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's question. In addition, you don't typically use URL paths when navigating with `ui-router`. Instead you navigate with the state name either via `ui-sref` or `$state.go()`. The URL paths are there for deep linking when you share a URL (via email, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The point is: each `.` *(dot)* in state name represents nesting. I.e

```
// child of the 'app' state
.state('app.report_moveFrom', {
// child of the above 'app.report_moveFrom'
.state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
```

Also, any view targeting, is using by default relative naming. It means, UI-Router searches for *(un)named* view in the parent state. So, the `'app.report_moveFrom'` must contain **`app.report_moveFrom`** if we use this syntax as this:

```
// parent for next state
.state('app.report_moveFrom', {
...
// the default view name resolution is related to parent
.state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
  url: '/drillDown',
  views:{
     // that ui-view="main" target must be in the above state
    'main': {
    ...
```

and finally, if we have a child, it inherits the parent **url** as well

```
// parent url
.state('app.report_moveFrom', {
  url: '/reports/moveFrom',
  ...
})
//child url - is later extended with parent part
.state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
  url: '/drillDown',
  ...
  // and in runtime this state has '/reports/moveFrom' +  '/drillDown'
  // i.e.: '/reports/moveFrom/drillDown'
```

But we can change this default behavior, with just a few tricks.

1) Reset url, to start at root, and 2) target grand parent, with absolute view naming

```
.state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
  // this sign at the beginning will rest url evaluation - to root level
  url: '^/drillDown',
  views:{
    // we use absolute naming here, so this state will be placed into grand parent 'app'
    'main@app': {
      ...
```

But the best would be *(in my view)* simply remove the `'.'` from the state name, and by default create a **sibling** *(not a child)*

```
.state('app.report_moveFrom', {
// remove dot
//.state('app.report_moveFrom.drillDown', {
.state('app.report_moveFrom_drillDown', {
```

...and now all will be working by design - because we did **not** created **too much nested** state